# Twitter rest api "/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json" return blank

Tags: swift, twitter, oauth, timeline

This link is post tweet.
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests

My app is done in post tweet by that link.

But https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

I programming user_timeline. But I can't.

Just return blank.

My iPhone app's OAuth is verify correctly by https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests link.

Why return blank ?

How do I do? User_timeline don't need OAuth?

I programming User_timeline applied my oauth, Is not ?

**Did block from twitter company ?**

Comment: I don't think it is clear what you are asking here. Can you add some code or details of the HTTP operations you're using to call the API, so folks can see where you might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use codebird from https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php/blob/develop/src/codebird.php.

And timeline info is

```
$cb->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

$reply = (array) $cb->statuses_homeTimeline();
print_r($reply);
```

Comment: Thanks you answer. But I use SWIFT. I really wonder WHY twitter company has blocked.